# How can i change this query to ORM? (JOIN without foreign key and order by second table)

Tags: python, django, orm

Hi i have two models like this,

```py
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)  ##
    processid = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # 


class Process(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="process_set")
    endstat = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ENDSTATChoice, default='0')
```

and I want to join Sample and Process model. Because Sample is related to process and I want to get process information with sample .

```sql
SELECT sample.id, sample.name, process.id,process.endstat
FROM sample 
INNER JOIN process 
ON sample.processid = process.id 
ORDER BY process.endstat;
```

How can i do with ORM like this SQL?

Comment: What exactly was the difficulty? Do you know how to do any other query with ORM?

Comment: I can't  **join without foreign key** and order... my boss set the model like this..

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the data of the `Process`. It makes more sense to work with:

```
qs = Process.objects.filter(
    sample__isnull=False
).select_related('sample').order_by('endstat')
```

This will also fetch the related data for the related `Sample`, you thus can process this by accessing the fields of the `.sample` attribute:

```
for process in qs:
    print(process.sample.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for reading and replying. but Can i get with Sample queryset? I need Sample's queryset..

Comment: @Shale: but it makes no sense: you can access the sample with `.sample`: since your queryset also contains the values for the process, the way to query is from the `Process` model.

Comment: Thanks.. but I leave out the fact that I already have Sample queryset filtered before those query, and I need to filter to **that** Sample queryset..

Comment: @Shale: you can filter the `Sample`, with `Process.objects.filter(sample__name='my_name')` for example, so by using the `sample__` prefix, you filter on the related model.